# La función round() no funciona como quiero PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de redondear un número con PHP y no obtengo el valor esperado, el número a redondear es:

```
$valor = 6.3546;
```

Y debería obtener:

```
$valor = 6.36;
```

Estoy usando:

```
round($valor , 2);
```

He buscando en la documentación y tampoco funcionan otras opciones. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No he especificado que necesitaba un redondeo al alza. Si queréis cerrar la pregunta me parece bien.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con el cierre. Si indica un valor de entrada y un resultado esperado de salida; las palabras exactas empleadas (`redondeo` o `redondeo al alza`) no son mas que eso, palabras. Se proporcionan los datos mínimos necesarios.

Comment: @Trauma yo tampoco estoy deacuerdo con el cierre, por eso me anime a dar una respuesta un poco mas completa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Realmente `round` esta haciendo su trabajo correctamente.

Las 2 reglas básicas del redondeo son:

> 1º Se escoge el número más cercano que tenga la cantidad de dígitos significativos escogida.
>
> 2º Si ambos número más cercanos con la cantidad de dígitos significativos escogidos son igual de cercanos se escoge el que tiene como último dígito significativo un número par (múltiplo de 2)

Por defecto [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) utiliza el modo `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` que indica lo siguiente:

> **PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP**: Redondea valor hacia arriba a precisión lugares decimales alejándose de cero, cuando está a medio camino. Hace que 1.5 sea 2, y -1.5 sea -2.

Es decir que si hay las mismas posiciones (distancia) entre los valores mas cercanos redondea al mas lejano de 0.

---

Ahora revisemos el número `6.3546`, los dos valosres mas cercanos de 2 decimales son `6.3500` y `6.3600`. Veamos cuál es el mas cercano:

```
Número | Redondeo | Posiciones
------------------------------
6.3546 | 6.3500   | 46 posiciones
6.3546 | 6.3600   | 54 posiciones
```

Por lo tanto podemos determinar que el redondeo correcto es `6.35`

---

Ahora bien, si lo que queremos es redondear siempre al alza, por pequeña que sea la fracción podemos apoyarnos en [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) y [pow()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pow.php) y en las matemáticas, un ejemplo:

```
<?php
// Definimos el valor
$valor = 6.3546;
// Definimos el número de decimales
$precision = 2;
// Multiplicamos el valor por la base decimal (10) elevado al número de decimales(2)
// con esto conseguimos pasar los decimales a la parte entera
$valor = $valor * pow(10, $precision); // 635.46
// Con ceil redondeamos al siguiente entero más alto
$valor =  ceil($valor); //636
// Dividimos el valor por la base decimal (10) elevado al número de decimales(2)
// con esto recuperamos los decimales
$valor = $valor / pow(10, $precision); // 6.36

echo $valor; // 6.36


// Simplificando
$valor = 6.3546;
$precision = 2;
echo ceil($valor * pow(10, $precision)) / pow(10, $precision);
```

Mas ejemplos

```
<?php
$valor = 6.3546;
echo ceil($valor*100)/100; //6.36

$valor = 6.35000001;
echo ceil($valor*100)/100; //6.36

$valor = 6.35;
echo ceil($valor*100)/100; //6.35
```

Comment: Xerif, gracias por la excelente explicación!!

Comment: Genial la explicación, excelente detalle!

Comment: Un espectáculo de respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Prueba hacer esto:

```
$valor = 6.3546;
round($valor * 100) / 100
```

Primero lo multiplicamos por 100. Tenemos el valor 635.46; Ahora hacemos el redondeo, puesto que los 0.46 queremos deshacernos de ellos. Haríamos un round(635.46) que devuelve como resultado 635. Por último, a este valor lo dividimos por 100, para recuperar los decimales, lo que nos da 6.36, que es el valor que deseas obtener.

Comment: ¿Realmente tu has probado el código que pones? `$valor = 6.3546; echo round($valor * 100) / 100;` **Si divides 635 entre 100, nunca puede dar `6.36`**.