# Redondeo Decimales PHP

Tags: php, redondeo

Un saludo a toda la comunidad de stack overflow, me podrían ayudar con el redondeo de decimales en PHP?

```html
<?php

$bs = 10215251;

$formatbs = number_format($bs, 2, ',', '.');

$reconver = $bs / 1000;

$redondeo = round($reconver, 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

$formatbss = number_format($redondeo, 3, ',', '.');

echo $formatbs." Bs<br>";

echo $formatbss." BsS<br>";
?>
```

Cuando el tercer número (milésima) sea diferente de cero, se debe aumentar el segundo número (centésima) al céntimo superior, pero no logro hacerlo :S...

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta creo que es lo que buscas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163691/38103

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el tercer lugar es centésima, pero según lo entendido te comparto esta solución.

```
    <?php

    $bs = 10215551;
    function redondear($bs){
        $numeroConDecimales = $bs/pow(10,3);
        $numeroSinDecimales = floor($numeroConDecimales);
        $soloDecimales = round($numeroConDecimales-$numeroSinDecimales,3);
        $redondeo = ceil($soloDecimales*pow(10,2));
        $number = $numeroSinDecimales+$redondeo/pow(10,2);
        return $number*pow(10,2);
    }
    $redondeadoCentena= redondear($bs);
    echo $redondeadoCentena;echo "\n";
    echo number_format($redondeadoCentena/1000, 3, ',', '.');

    ?>
```

Comment: bueno no entendí muy bien tu script, lo que quisiera es redondear la centésima cuando la milesima sea mayor a 0 ejemplo:

10.215,551
10.215,56

Comment: prueba otra ves el script. masomenos te voy entendiendo. lo que quisiera saber es si tu entrada es un número con decimales o entero.

Answer (score 0):

Tan simple como esto

```
$x=9.992929323;
echo round($x,0);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Fue reportada como de baja calidad. Podrias explicar un poco lo que hiciste? y porque soluciona el problema? mira por favor [answer]