# Reducir cifra en porcentaje

Tags: php

He sacado el porcentaje de una cantidad, pero quiero reducir la cifra que me arroja, aqui el resultado que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo quiero que me muestre: 0.1%

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
    <?php
        $porc="";

        $porc=(($total/$data['total'])*100);
    ?>
    <?php echo $porc ;?>%
```

Comment: No veo por qué usar la etiqueta mysql

Comment: Puedes revisar esta respuesta hacerca de redondeo y truncado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163166/la-funci%c3%b3n-round-no-funciona-como-quiero-php/163691#163691

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo que ofrece php para rendondear numeros

```
$porc=(($total/$data['total'])*100);
$porc = round($porc, 2);
```

Comment: Gracias a los dos por su ayuda, solucionado mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías formatearlo la salida usando sprintf

```
<?php echo sprintf("%.1f%%", $porc); ?>
```

Eso formatearla un numero a string que representa un entero de punto flotante con 1 decimal y el símbolo porcentual)

```
0.1%
```

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo necesitas utilizar la función [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) de **PHP**

Para sacar el valor que quieres puedes hacerlo así:

```
round( $porc, 1);
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
    $porc="";

    $porc=(($total/$data['total'])*100);

?>

<?php echo round( $porc, 1);?>%
```