# Redondear decimales a multiplo de 5 con php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando redondear un numero para que passe de 1.2 a 1.5 y no logro hacerlo.

Estoy intentando con este codigo

```
round(format_rl(1.2),2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Pero no logro que el redondeo sea el correcto. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Pero redondear es pasar un número por ejemplo 1.2 a 1 que es su minimo mas cercano o 1.5 a 2 que sería su maximo mas cercano, ¿cuál es la lógica a seguir para pasar de 1.2 a 1.5?, ¿siempre será un incremento de 3 decimales?

Comment: Revisa está respuesta, creo que aclarará tus dudas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163166/la-funci%c3%b3n-round-no-funciona-como-quiero-php/163691?r=SearchResults#163691

Comment: Necesito que pase al proximo 5 mas cercano. El decimal. Por ejemplo 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 se transaforma en 1.5 y 1.6, 1.7, 1.8,, 1.9 se transforma en 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Propongo que separes la parte decimal de la entera.
Conviertas la parte decimal a entero potencia de 10. Esto es porque después `ceil()` truncará todos los demás decimales.
Luego lo divides entre 5, porque se quiere redondear en base a 5.
Le calculas el redondeo hacia arriba `ceil()`
Ahora reviertes las pre-operaciones, lo vuelves a multiplicar por 5 y se divide entre 10.

Se lee más enredado de lo que en realidad es, la fórmula sería algo así

```
$decimal_redondeado = ceil($decimal*10/5) *5 / 10;
```

Haciendo las respectivas simplificaciones, el código en una función quedaría algo como:

```
function redondear($n) {
    $ent = floor($n); // Parte entera
    $dec = $n - $ent; // Parte decimal
    $r = ceil($dec*2) / 2; // Decimal redondeado
    return $ent + $r;
}
```

> ```
> echo redondear(1.2); // 1.5
> echo redondear(1.5); // 1.5
> echo redondear(1.6); // 2
> echo redondear(3.0); // 3
> ```